# Index of the current position inside of a python loop with increments?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, increment

I'm trying to write an array of values within two nested loops over another ndarray with at the corresponding position. Enumerate does not work, because of the increments.

My example-Code does the job, but I'm fairly certain, there are more elegant ways:

```
basearray = np.array([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
             [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
             [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
             [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]])

stepx=0
stepy=0
incrementx=2
incrementy=2
resultarray=np.zeros(((len(basearray)),len(basearray[1])))

for x in basearray[::incrementx]:
    stepy=0
    for y in x[::incrementy]:
        resultarray[stepx][stepy]=y*2
        stepy=stepy+incrementy
    stepx=stepx+incrementx
print(resultarray)

[[ 20.   0.  60.   0. 100.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 50.   0.  54.   0.  58.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

How can I solve that?

Very best and thank you in advance

Christian

Comment: `position_of_x` and `position_of_y` variables are not defined. Your code won't execute

Comment: `resulting_array=[[0]*4]*4`  never do that. define an array of zeros with `np.zeros((4,4))` Otherwise yor resulting array just contains copies of references to the same element.

Comment: ok, now you just loop over the even indexes (0,2), something like `for x in range(0:4:2)`  same for `y`, then just do `resulting_array[x][y] = 'result'`

Comment: According to the result you want to achieve, resulting array is (4, 5) not (4, 4)

Comment: Thank you very much so far! If I use "range", I get the error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

For example:

for x in range(basearray[::2]):
    for y in range(x[::2]):
        print(y)

does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My original code is a little more complex. I have a matrix of 160x40 pixels and want to store curve-fitting-results in a separate matrix for every pixel. But the calculation is time consuming, so I want to be able to do it just with a fraction of the base values.

Comment: so it's an XY problem where you want do downsample an image?

Comment: Googleing "XY Problem" didn't give me an answer, so I can's answer for sure, if this is such a problem. I want to store data for each corresponding pixel. Downsampling it would make a assignment to the specific position in the base array imposible.

Comment: I edited my question because my first post was kind of misleading. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are intialising zeroes in the form of list the desired output can be achievable**

**Code:-**

```
import numpy as np
basearray=np.array([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                     [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
                     [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
                     [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]])
resulting_array1=([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
for lis in range(0,len(basearray)-1,2):
    for y in range(0,len(basearray[0]),2):
        resulting_array1[lis][y]='result'
print(resulting_array1)
```

**Output:-**

```
[['result', 0, 'result', 0, 'result'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['result', 0, 'result', 0, 'result'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

**Points to remember:-**

**(1) The elements of a NumPy array must all be of the same type. you can not change integer type to string type `result`**

Code:-2 **Using np array**

```
import numpy as np
basearray=np.array([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                     [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
                     [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
                     [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]])
resulting_array2=np.array([['0    ', '0', '0     ', '0', '0     '],
                           ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
                           ['0    ', '0', '0    ', '0', '0    '],
                           ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']])
for lis in range(0,len(basearray)-1,2):
    for y in range(0,len(basearray[0]),2):
        resulting_array2[lis][y]='result'
print(resulting_array2)
```

**Output:-**

```
[['result' '0' 'result' '0' 'result']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['result' '0' 'result' '0' 'result']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0']]
```

**Note you have to give spaces in 0 when initialising..!**

**i.e if you give two spaces with 0 it will return only `res` so to return result you have to write 0 with 4 spaces to print result**

**Updated query:-**

check before this `resulting_array2[lis][y]='result'` using `if` statement

**Code:-**

```
for lis in range(0,len(basearray)-1,1):
    for y in range(0,len(basearray[0]),2):
        if len(basearray)-1>=lis and len(basearray[0])-1>=y:
            resulting_array2[lis][y]='result'
```

Comment: This works quite well, but it results in an error, if the increment is larger than the list index. Is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: check the updated query.. if still not resolved please let me know..!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, one approach is to do:

```
import numpy as np

basearray = np.array([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                      [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
                      [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
                      [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]])

resulting_array = np.zeros((4, 5))

resulting_array[::2, ::2] = basearray[::2, ::2]
print(resulting_array)
```

**Output**

```
[[10.  0. 30.  0. 50.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [25.  0. 27.  0. 29.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: but this doesn't create the result the OP requested. He requested a list of lists with 0 everywhere except the string "result" in certain positions

Comment: As I said, I'm assuming the OP want the values of basearray at that position, otherwise why put basearray in the question an iterate over it?

Comment: Also in the question, you can read: "I'm trying to write an array of values within two nested loops over another ndarray with at the corresponding position."